# Symfony template rendering syntax style

Tags: symfony

A question which I am asking myself since a while:

Can anyone tell me if there is a difference in rendering a template with 
`@-annotation` or in `colon-style`:

```
@Acme/AcmeBundle/Default/index.html.twig
Acme:AcmeBundle:Default:index.html.twig
```

and if there is a difference what is it,
if not which is the newer/proper one and should be used accordingly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both namespaced templates and traditional template will work as expected in views but it wont work in controllers. Please check [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/PHP.html)

```
    // namespaced templates will no longer work in controllers
    $this->render('@App/Default/index.html.twig');

    // you must use the traditional template notation
    $this->render('AppBundle:Default:index.html.twig');

{# inside a Twig template, namespaced templates work as expected #}
{{ include('@App/Default/index.html.twig') }}

{# traditional template notation will also work #}
{{ include('AppBundle:Default:index.html.twig') }}
```

The **namespaced syntax is faster**.

Please refer [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/namespaced_paths.html) for more info

Comment: Haven't found this in the docs... thanks for digging out the reference